# Change the public default schema in doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Is there any way to change the default schema **public** in doorkeeper config?

I tried to change the schema in the migrations, but AcessToken and AccessGrant models does not bind automatically with the new schema in migrations

Where is the right way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set `table_name_prefix` for Doorkeeper models in the following way (something like that):

```rb
#config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb

Doorkeeper.configure do
  # ...
end

Doorkeeper::Application.table_name_prefix = "some_schema."
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.table_name_prefix = "some_schema."
Doorkeeper::AccessGrant.table_name_prefix = "some_schema."
```

Or even change full table name, but I don't recommend it:

```rb
Doorkeeper::Application.class_eval { self.table_name = :apps }
```